# posting location data in json format to server using intent service

Tags: android, service, http-post, intentservice

I have a small issue with posting json object to localhost server using intent service (i am using the emulator). I don't have any errors and i know the intent service onHandleIntent class is running. But on my server side i get no data. I doubt the data is actually sent. Can anybody help with this issue. Check my code below.

The intent service class:

```
public class GpsIntentService extends IntentService {

InputStream in = null;
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT    =    5000; //in milliseconds.
public static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT        =    7000; //in milliseconds.

private static HttpClient httpClient;

public GpsIntentService() {
    super("GpsIntentService");
}

private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
    if (httpClient == null) {
        httpClient  =  new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpParams params  =  httpClient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
    }
    return httpClient;

}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Bundle bundles = new Bundle();
    Bundle bundles = intent.getExtras();

    Double lat_data = bundles.getDouble("LAT_DATA");
    Double lng_data = bundles.getDouble("LNG_DATA");
    Double alt_data = bundles.getDouble("ALT_DATA");
    float spd_data = bundles.getFloat("SPD_DATA");
    float bearing_data = bundles.getFloat("BRNG_DATA");

    //Do the try and get for http client and convert to json obj here.
    HttpClient httpclient  =  getHttpClient();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    try {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8080/location/script.php");

        jsonObject.put("jsonLatitude", lat_data);
        jsonObject.put("jsonLongitude", lng_data);
        jsonObject.put("jsonAltitude", alt_data);
        jsonObject.put("jsonSpeed", spd_data);
        jsonObject.put("jsonBearing", bearing_data);

        Log.i("","Json data: "+ jsonObject.toString());

        //httppost.setHeader("json", jsonObject.toString());
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
        //se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

        httppost.setEntity(se); 
        HttpResponse res = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        if (res != null) {
            in = res.getEntity().getContent();

        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in  ,"UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        String result = sb.toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Result from buffer reader :" + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction(ResultReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
        broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("RESPONSE", result);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

        in.close();
     }
     catch(Exception e) {
         Log.e("Buffer reader error:", "Could not convert result to string" + e.toString());
     }

}
```

}

My main actvity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

gpsCoordinatesData coordinatesData;
private ResultReceiver results;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    IntentFilter intentfilter = new IntentFilter(ResultReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
    intentfilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    results = new ResultReceiver();
    registerReceiver(results, intentfilter);

}

public void buttonServiceHandler(View target) {

    coordinatesData = new gpsCoordinatesData(this);

Double lat = coordinatesData.getLatitude();
    Double lon = coordinatesData.getLongitude();
    Double alt = coordinatesData.getAltitude();
    float spd = coordinatesData.getSpeed();
    float brng = coordinatesData.getBearing();

    Intent intentTest = new Intent(this, GpsIntentService.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putDouble("LAT_DATA", lat);
    bundle.putDouble("LNG_DATA", lon);
    bundle.putDouble("ALT_DATA", alt);
    bundle.putFloat("SPD_DATA", spd);
    bundle.putFloat("BRNG_DATA", brng);

    intentTest.putExtras(bundle);

    startService(intentTest);

}

public class ResultReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String ACTION_RESP = "com.example.intent.action.MESSAGE_PROCESSED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String response = intent.getStringExtra("RESPONSE");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Results from broadcast receiver :" + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    this.unregisterReceiver(results);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

And the location class:

```
public class gpsCoordinatesData implements LocationListener {

private Context context;
Location location;

private boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
private boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

boolean canGetLocation = false;

Criteria c=new Criteria();

String provider;

Double longitude;
Double latitude;
float speed;
Double altitude;
float bearing;

protected LocationManager locationmanager; 

private static final int CHECK_COORDINATE_TIME_VALUE = 1000 * 60 * 2;


public gpsCoordinatesData(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    getgpsLocation();
}

protected boolean isGPSEnabled() {
    return locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


}

protected boolean isNetworkEnabled() {
    return locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public Location getgpsLocation() {
    try {
        locationmanager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
             // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            isNetworkEnabled = locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);



            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                // Setting Dialog Title
                alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

                // Setting Dialog Message
                alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

                // On pressing Settings button, to display settings pages
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                context.startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });

                // on pressing cancel button, to cancel
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                // Showing Alert Message
                alertDialog.show();
            }
            else {
                provider = locationmanager.getBestProvider(c, false);
                locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, CHECK_COORDINATE_TIME_VALUE, 0, this);
                if (locationmanager != null) {

                    location = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                    if(location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        altitude = location.getAltitude();
                        speed = location.getSpeed();
                        bearing = location.getBearing();

                   }
            }

        }

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return location;

}

public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
    return longitude;

}

public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }
    return latitude;

}

public double getAltitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        altitude = location.getAltitude();
    }
    return altitude;

}

public float getSpeed() {
    if (location != null) {
        speed = location.getSpeed();
    }
    return speed;

}

public float getBearing() {
    if (location != null) {
        bearing = location.getBearing();
    }
    return bearing;

}

public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationmanager != null) {
        locationmanager.removeUpdates(gpsCoordinatesData.this);
    }
}
```

}

And finally my php page:

```
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$data = var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

if(!empty($data)) {
    echo $lat = $data['jsonLatitude'];
    echo $lng = $data['jsonLongitude'];
    echo $alt = $data['jsonAltitude'];
    echo $spd = $data['jsonSpeed'];
    echo $brg = $data['jsonBearing'];


}
```